# Passing arguments to another function automatically

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, arrow-functions, aws-step-functions

I'm working on a Typescript boilerplate for AWS lambdas, and I'm trying to make it as short as possible. Here's how my handler looks like:

```
export const main = async event => findUsers;

const findUsers = event => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
  });
```

The `main` function is supposed to pass all of its own arguments to `findUsers`, but it doesn't.

Of course I could just call it as `findUsers(event)` and that works. But this is boilerplate code which is going to be used in potentially thousands of similar lambdas. I would prefer if the other devs won't need to specify what to pass, just let it happen.

The arguments aren't passed though. I did it countless times before, but it doesn't work now. Why is that?

Can it be a Typescript rule? Here's the relevant part of `tsconfig.json`:

```
"target": "ES2018",
"module": "commonjs",
"lib": ["es2018", "ESNext.AsyncIterable", "DOM"],
"types": ["node"],
"allowJs": true,
"checkJs": true,
"removeComments": true,
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"declaration": true,
"strict": true,
"noImplicitAny": false,
"strictNullChecks": true,
"strictPropertyInitialization": true,
"noImplicitThis": false,
"alwaysStrict": true,
"noUnusedLocals": false,
"noUnusedParameters": false,
"noImplicitReturns": false,
"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"inlineSourceMap": true,
"inlineSources": true,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
"isolatedModules": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Stepfunctions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-task-state.html#amazon-states-language-task-state-lambda)

This should also help https://medium.com/@tturnbull/passing-data-between-lambdas-with-aws-step-functions-6f8d45f717c3